# Upgrade to OSX 10.9 from 10.8 causes random restarts

Tags: macos, kernel-panic, kernel, restart

I recently upgraded my MacBook Pro (late 2011, core i5 2.4ghz, 8 gigs of ram) to OSX 10.9 from 10.8 (which in turn I upgraded from Lion).

The installation seemed to go well and everything was great until the OS booted up.
Every time the OS boots up (doesn't matter if I log in with my user or not) it restarts itself after a random amount of minute (5 minutes avg.).

Steps taken:

1. Reset SMC
2. Reset NVRAM
3. Permissions fix in disk utility
4. Remove login items
5. Clean caches

Nothing worked... I do have the kernel panic dump if anyone would like to look at it.
Anyway, I really don't want to re-install the system and hope you can give me more advice.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that I can work in safe mode without a problem (except it being slower than usual mode).

Here is the link to the Kernel panic file:

http://pastebin.com/mn4JJDb9

Comment: Does the machine boot into [safe mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1455) and stay running for any longer than 5 min? Go ahead and post the kernel panic report if you've got one...

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention it, it does... I can work in safe mode and did it yesterday for hours... I will post the panic in a min.

Comment: OK, I've added the latest kernel panic I got (working in safe mode for now)

Comment: I'm having in a similar issue on my 2011 27" Core i5 Imac. My guess in my case it is related to Time Machine not being able to access the back up drive when it wants to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm betting that it's this kernel extension:

```
com.silex.driver.sxuptp
```

Do you have anything that matches that name in /Library/Extensions (likely), or /System/Library/Extensions? If so, it may help to remove the file and reboot.

It appears that this software may be related to [a Belkin product](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1917187?tstart=0)

Comment: I have this folder: /System/Library/Extensions/SXUPTP.kext Should I just go ahead and remove it (move to different location) ?

Comment: Yes - you should move it out of that folder. By default, simply dragging it out of the folder will not remove it. It may be possible to move the file to the Trash (and authenticate as an Administrator) to get it out of there.

Comment: i'm using the CLI so "mv" should do it I suppose :) Thanks i'll try it and update this question soon

Comment: Or an 'rm' ;) ...

Comment: hehe... rm is kinda un-reversible :P I looked at that post you added to this answer.. I don't have their hardware so I don't care... Anyway... I hope I'm not jinxing it but it seems to work for 25 min straight which is longer than yesterday. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you - Very helpful - I had the same rebooting issue after installing silex virtual port software for printing from Dlink Router USB Port

Model Identifier: MacBookPro8,1
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.8 GHz
  System Version:   Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63b)

Removing the program and this file fixed the issue
/System/Library/Extensions/SXUPTP.kext

Resolved